# How to handle 3d texture on webgl2

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am trying to work with 3D texture in webgl2 and I came to know about the

```
gl.texImage3D();
```

I have experience with 2d texture and I found it very convenient but there is another approach that people are using on the internet.

---

```
gl.texStorage3D()
```

and then,

```
gl.texSubImage3D() // with all offset of x,y and z as 0.
```

---

I just want to know what is the difference between the two approaches. I came to know that equivalent of the second option is available for the 2D texture as well but I don't use it to provide data to the target. I know that subimage is to create texture's subimage to the fragment shader but I don't understand what is the difference between two approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is `texStorage2D` and `texStorage3D` allocate all of the texture memory up front. Where as `texImage2D` and `texImage3D` allocate one mip level at a time.

`texSubImage2D` and `texSubImage3D` do not allocate anything. They just copy data into a texture mip level that was previously allocated with one of the functions above.

As for why one or the other. `texStorage2D` and `texStorage3D` can immediately allocate memory on the GPU. `texImage2D` and `texImage3D` can not since they don't know the complete texture (all the mips) until you actually try to draw something with the texture. To put it another way, `texStorage2D/3D` *might* be more efficient where as `texImage2D/3D` is more flexible.

---

In order for a texture to actually be renderable, all the mip levels you are going to use need to be the same internal format and the correct sizes.

When you call `texStorage2D/3D` you tell the size of mip level 0 (the largest level) and how many mip levels in total to allocate. So let's say you tell it an internal format of `gl.RGBA8`, width and height of 8 and 4 mip levels.

```
gl.texStorage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,
                4,         // 4 levels
                gl.RGBA8,  // internal format
                8,         // width
                8);        // height
```

It will allocate 8x8x4, 4x4x4, 2x2x4, 1x1x4 mip levels, all 4 mip levels. It knows they are all RGBA8. It knows they are all the correct size. Textures allocated with `texStorage2D` can't be changed in size or internal format. If you try to call `texImage2D` on a texture created with `texStorage2D` you'll get an error.

If you instead used `texImage2D` well first you probably specify the first mip

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 
              0,         // mip level
              gl.RGBA8,  // internal format
              8,         // width
              8,         // height
              0,         // border
              gl.RGBA,   // data format
              gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,  // data type
              data);
```

so now you have just 1 mip level, level #0.  Will you add the other 3 mips? Will they be the correct size? Will those other 3 mips have the same internal format? Will you change mip level #0 to something else, a different size, or different internal format? WebGL doesn't have any idea what your next command will be, it has to wait until you actually try to draw with the texture before it can check. With `texStorage` you decide the sizes and formats of all the mips up front so it only has to check one time. With `texImage` you don't tell it everything up front so it has to check at draw time again if things change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. do you mean that texStorage allocate memory for different level beforehand and texImage2D allocate at drawcall, right? I don't understand why you say texStorage efficient since it may take memory space for the level that may not be used and i don't understand how texImage is flexible than texStorage.

Comment: If you think through the implications of the API you could figure this out on your own but I added more info.

Comment: that's very helpful info that helped me to clear my confusion to a high extend. Thank you alot for your effort and time.